# Can't catch InvalidFileException

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to get a path of a file via filedialog from tkinter but instead of choosing a file I'm closing the window to browse for that file which makes my GUI go a bit crazy.
When I close the browsing window I see the following log:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shtlrs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Invoice handling\GUITest.py", line 76, in browseXLL
    self.man = xManip.XManip(file)
  File "D:\Invoice handling\xManip.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.sheet = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
  File "D:\Invoice handling\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)
  File "D:\Invoice handling\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "D:\Invoice handling\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

What I want to do is restart the GUI ( or maybe eventually another action) when I close the browsing window
here's the bit of code that's supposed to handle the situation:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import InvalidFileException
...

    def browseXLL(self,event):
        try:
            file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        except InvalidFileException:

            self.window.destroy()
            self.__init__()
```

but the error is n

Comment: `file = filedialog.askopenfilename()` is not where the exception comes from. Have alook in the stack trace. Either wrap `self.man = xManip.XManip(file)` in the try except in GUITest.py or wrap `self.sheet = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)` in xManip.py

Comment: Oh great, thanks man. It works. I just wrapped self.man = xManip.XManip(file) in the try except